# Webpack's alias doesn't work when target module is in node_modules

Tags: webpack

### Background

I'm writing an SSR react app with typescript, there's a client-side module I have to use (`client-logger`) and it can only be run on client-side since it's AMD module system. running on Node will give errors.

My current solution is to replace the `client-logger` module with a `rewrite-client-logger` module at compile time ONLY for server bundle.

I have tried Webpack's `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` and `alias`, even write my own loader, none of them works, this is my [Webpack config](https://github.com/stanleyyylau/demo/blob/master/webpack.config.js) for the alias.

This is the demo link for repro: https://github.com/stanleyyylau/demo

#### Repro Steps:

- Git clone and checkout to Master branch
- `npm install` to install all dependencies
- copy `client-logger` to node_modules with `cp -rf ./client-logger ./node_modules`
- `npm run build` to trigger the build
- `npm run start` to run the universal app

#### Expected result:

- Server should be running with no error
- Server bundle's `client-logger` should be replaced by `rewrite-client-logger` ( You can verify this by searching for the string `register event` in `assets/server.js` file.)

#### Actual result:

- Node gives runtime error `ReferenceError: define is not defined`
- `client-logger` is not being replaced by `rewrite-client-logger` (alias replacement only works when `client-logger` is not in `node_modules` folder.)

  if anyone has other ways to replace module at compile time, please let me know, highly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the issue by changing your **webpack-node-externals** configuration to include the logger. That way the alias rule has a chance to work. Try

```
externals: [nodeExternals({
    whitelist: ['client-logger']
})]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Juho, But it is still not working, after adding it to whitelist, I think it's been replaced, but I'm getting another error: https://gist.github.com/stanleyyylau/a0f96aeefa91baf38861a002280fc56b   Very frustrating, the normalModuleReplacement also don't work

Comment: I think you are bundling Node `path` to the client bundle. I cannot reproduce the error as navigating to the app root gives 404. I would need more accurate information to debug this further.